# Sending a renamed file using Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

Let's say I have a save file, `saves.xyz`, and I want to share it, by mail.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, content.getShareSubject());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content.getShareText());

File savesFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filePath);
Uri savesUri = Uri.fromFile(savesFile);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, savesUri);

String fileType = activity.getString(R.string.saves_file_type); //"text/xyz"
intent.setType(fileType);

String chooserMessage = activity.getString(R.string.saves_chooser_message);
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, chooserMessage));
```

This works fine enough.

---

However, I now want to be able to **rename the attached file** (say `saves-01-01-2017.xyz`).

I've thought about copying the file, sending it, then deleting it, but haven't found a way to delete it cleanly afterwards (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23222702/7041501)).

I also tried to implement my own `FileProvider` (as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14099252/7041501)) and redirecting `saves-*.xyz` to `saves.xyz`, but I couldn't get the `FileProvider` to work (I probably didn't grasp their function fully) :

**manifest.xml**

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mydomain.myapp"
    >
    ...
    <application
        ...
        >
        <provider
            android:name="com.mydomain.myapp.MyFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"
            />
        </provider>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**file_provider_paths.xml**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path 
        name="saves_folder"
        path="/"
    />
</paths>
```

**MyFileProvider class**

```
public class MyFileProvider extends FileProvider {
    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //doesn't print anything
        Log.d(MyFileProvider.class.getSimpleName(), uri.toString()); 
        return super.openFile(uri, mode);
    }
}
```

I'd be grateful if I were to be enlightened here.

Comment: `I now want to be able to rename the attached file`. What a fuss. First rename the file. Then attach it.

Comment: There is nothing for a send intent to specify a name.

Comment: @greenapps Maybe I wasn't clear. I want the attached file to have a different name, but I don't want to change my file's name nor have leftover files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a cleaner way than `FileProvider` (felt way too overkill, and I couldn't get it to work anyway), using `startActivityForResult` and `onSaveInstanceState`.

Copying the file to the desired name:

```
try {
    copyFile(saves_file, saves_tmp_file);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    return false;
}
Uri saves_uri = Uri.fromFile(saves_tmp_file) ;
```

Starting the intent's activity with `startActivityForResult`:

```
activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, chooserMessage), 
                                MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Saving the temporary file's name in the activity's state:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outstate.putCharArray(TO_DELETE_PATH_BUNDLE_KEY, tmpFilePath.toCharArray());
}
```

Restoring it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        char[] array = savedInstanceState.getCharArray(TO_DELETE_PATH_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (array != null)
            tmpFilePath = new String(array);
    {
}
```

Deleting the file:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE && tmpFilePath != null)
        new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), tmpFilePath).delete();
}
```

---

I guess this method isn't the safest, but it should be safe and clean enough for my uses.

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna try this way

```
File savesFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filePath);

//rename your file here
File rename = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "renameithere.txt");
if (savesFile.exists()) {
   savesFile.renameTo(rename);
}
```

Also if you're using a FileProvider, then use this way to get the Uri.

```
try {
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, viewFile);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    return Uri.fromFile(viewFile);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried `getUriForFile`, sadly to no avail. Also, copying the file in the ext. cache could work indeed, but I'd like to avoid leaving useless files in it, so I'll keep it as a last resort option

Comment: Also, `getUriForFile` doesn't throw exceptions, so there's no need to catch from it